# How to force every row in a csv file to be a length of 982 comma seperated characters?

Tags: python, csv

For example, I have a file with in the format

```
Row one:AAACCCTTTGGGUU
Row two:CCTTGUAAGGUUTTTTTTTT
```

I would like for each row in the CSV to have 982 comma separated characters (minimum and maximum) meaning that if the first row doesnt have enough characters, it takes them from the second row to fulfill the minimum and maximum character count of 982 and so forth.

How could I go about this? I am absolutely stumped.

edit: the link to my data is http://www.filedropper.com/dna_1

edit: when I meant 982 characters per row I didnt mean including the commas. I meant 982 characters such as (CCTTGUAA). Therefore, for example, row one would take characters from row two until it has a total of 982 characters. This process would repeat until every row has 982 characters (not including the commas).

Comment: Working with DNA?

Comment: An entire genome! Pretty large file

Comment: Is the content of your file literally: `Row one:AAACCCTTTGGGUU` - or is it just the sequences per line (eg: `AAACCCTTTGGGUU`)? It doesn't look particularly CSV-ish...

Comment: And the output would be: `A,A,A,C,C,C,T,T,T,G,G,G,U,U,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,`... (with a lot more commas) ?

Comment: @JonClements No. The commas do not count as the number of characters. They only simply need to be there to create columns. Only the letters (CCTTGUAA for example) count as characters.

Comment: Huh? Your data doesn't have any commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming an input file of:

```
AAACCCTTTGGGUU
CCTTGUAAGGUUTTTTTTTT
```

Then you can build a generator to return all the characters across all lines on a line-by-line basis and then chunk them to write to the output file:

```
from itertools import islice

with open('input.txt') as fin, open('output.txt', 'w') as fout:
    chars = (ch for line in fin for ch in line.strip())
    for block in iter(lambda: list(islice(chars, 8)), []):
        print(*block, sep='', file=fout)
```

This'll give you an output of:

```
AAACCCTT
TGGGUUCC
TTGUAAGG
UUTTTTTT
TT
```

Adjust the separator to be `,` if you want commas and adjust the `islice` to be the length of each block required.

Comment: Beautiful! Worked like a charm! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
b = 982
with open("dna.csv") as f:
    c = f.read().replace("\n", "")
items = [c[i: i+b] for i in range(0, len(c), b)]
```

`items` will be a list of strings each of length `b` or, in your case, `982`.

Of course, this is assuming that the CSV is small enough to be fit into memory all at once.

Comment: I see. I’ll give it a shot. The csv is rather large though. It’s an entire genome

Comment: @xion You can definitely do that. However, the code will be a little longer.

Comment: Hm, this didnt seem to do anything. I loaded in my csv file and ran it but unfortunately no change whatsoever. The link to my data is http://www.filedropper.com/dna_1